# How to automatically generate useful scales for data driven pages in ArcGIS desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, scale, data-driven-pages

I have been tasked with creating several hundred maps of properties that intersect a long pipeline.  The maps will zoom to the part of the property which shows the intersection.  The lengths of pipeline that intersect the properties  is highly variable -from two metres to over 16,000 metres.  Therefore, each map will be at very different scales.

I am trying to work out a way to automate the updating of a SCALE field for use in data driven pages.  I have found that in general, for my maps, there is between a 1:4 to 1:5 ratio between the length of pipe segment to the scale.  That is, if the pipe segment is 1100 metres, then a useful scale would be about 1:5000.  I would prefer to round the scale up rather than down so that I can see the full feature on the map.

I want to avoid using scales that are not commonly used such as 1:7000 or 1:19,000, for example.  I have come up with the following solution for use in the field calculator:

```
import bisect
def scale(n):
  scaleMult=n*5
  scaleList=[500,1000,1250,1500,2000,2500,4000,5000,7500,10000,12500,15000,20000,25000,30000,40000,50000,75000,100000,150000,200000]
  roundedScale=scaleList[bisect.bisect(scaleList,scaleMult)]
  return roundedScale
```

The above code multiplies the length by some number (I chose 5) then finds out where in my predefined list of scales it should go and returns the next one higher.  The code works pretty well for about 90% of the properties.  I played around with the scaleMult variable and multiplied n by a few different values between 4 and 5 but nothing really improved the maps.

I was thinking that there might be a better solution.  If the pipe is not very straight and doubles back on itself slightly or has a major bend in it, then the feature didn't fit well on the map.  It was usually zoomed in too far.

One idea I had was to use the features bounding box.  Maybe there is a relationship between the feature's bounding box area and the scale.  But, if the bounding box is long and thin, the scale could be different to a bounding box that was a square of the same area.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement such a process?

Are there any better solutions that I'm not thinking of?

Looking for solutions in ArcGIS 10.1 and 10.2.

Comment: As a thought have you considered creating some sort of exceptions list?  Perhaps a Python dictionary with LotPlan as key and SuitableScale as value and then use algorithm if LotPlan not in dictionary, otherwise use SuitableScale found there.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I'm not sure that would work.  It's not based on LotPlan but on the length of pipe that intersects the lot.  It could intersect on a small corner of a very large property.  Also, sometimes the pipe can enter then exit, then reenter the property in a completely different place.

Comment: Perhaps a pipe segment ID is available to use in a similar fashion.

Comment: I'm not sure I've explained myself fully.  Using your method, I would still have to manually figure out the ideal scale for each pipe segment (or property).  I'm looking for a way to automatically generate an ideal scale for each feature.

Comment: I've been working on a similar process/solution.  You need to compare the size and trending direction of the features bounding box to that of your data frame (in layout view).  I've got some code that is close, which I will post when complete.

Comment: I think I do understand, its what I do in some of the Qld Govt's Online Environmental Mapping Service (OEMS), to deal with exceptional scales for some pipeline tenures, heritage sites and national parks.  Scales for the exceptions are worked out manually, but assuming the pipe locations are fairly static, it may be an expedient to do that for 20-30 rather than try to get an algorithm to address the last 10%.

Comment: @RyanDalton, Sounds great.  Looking forward to seeing your solution.

Comment: @PolyGeo, What I'm currently doing is for a pipeline which is still in design phase. However, what I'm trying to do should apply to any new Data Driven Page mapping project.  Whether it is pipeline segments, land parcels, or water bodies, or whatever.

Comment: @RyanDalton - just wondering if you ever finished your solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set up the DDP using the pipeline as the ddp layer. In the Python script, iterate over the pages and check the data frame scale. Using some conditional logic, you can calculate what the scale for that map should be, and then export.

Here is part of a script I have used in the past:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\MyMap.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
for i in range(0, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
    mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = i
    if df.scale < 1500:
        df.scale = 1500
    #do more things and export
```

In your case, you could use `if...elif` logic to cover all your scales you've included in your scale list (since you have worked them out already), or you could do some calculations to round the number up to the nearest 500 or 1000 or whatever you want.

This method calculates the scale each time the script is run, so if you are going to run it multiple times but don't envision the pipeline changing (though other layout elements might), you may need to add a field as suggested and use an `UpdateCursor` to save these scale values into it. You could then export the data driven pages from ArcMap using the scale field for your extent

Comment: This is a good solution.  I could probably merge it with my solution of using the bisect module.